# How can I define 2 classes from the same header file, while one class depends on the other?

Tags: c++, header-files

Im currently trying to implement a simple path-finding algorithm and need edges and nodes for it. I want to handle the implementation of those in one .h and one .cpp file. Right now I get the error "expected constructor, destructor or type conversion before ...".

I already tried separating both classes into 2 .h and .cpp-files, but that didnt work either. I've tried a lot of solutions provided for that error message, but nothing seems to work and I think there something Im missing right now.

My utilites.cpp file looks a bit like that

```
#include "utilities.h"

//Class Node
//Public

using namespace std;

Node::Node(string name)
{
  this->name = name;
}

//Class Edge
//public

Edge::Edge(Node::Node nSource, Node::Node nTarget, int weight)
{
  this->nSource = nSource;
  this->nTarget = nTarget;
  this->weight = weight;
}
```

and my utilities.h:

```
#ifndef UTILITIES_H
#define UTILITIES_H

#include <string>
#include <list>

class Node
{
public:
  Node(std::string);
  std::string name;
};


class Edge
{
public:
  Edge(Node, Node, int);
  Node nSource;
  Node nTarget;
  int weight;
};

#endif /* end of include guard: UTILITIES_H */
```

If I just use the Class Node, everything works.
But if I want implement Class Edge with the Class Node, I'll get the error previously mentioned. I think it is an easy solve, but I just cant figure it out.

I should say that I already tried it with

```
Edge::Edge(Node nSource, Node nTarget, int weight)
{
  this->nSource = nSource;
  this->nTarget = nTarget;
  this->weight = weight;
}
```

but that just gave me the error "No matching function for call to 'Node::Node()'

Comment: `Edge::Edge(Node::Node nSource, Node::Node nTarget, int weight)` -> `Edge::Edge(Node nSource, Node nTarget, int weight)`.

Comment: If I do that I just get the error "No matching function for call to Node::Node()". I had it like that originally, but some other forum told me to try that.

Comment: `Node::Node()` is the default constructor of class `Node`. Do you have it? Compiler just tells you what to do.

Comment: Since `Node` doesn't have default constructor, you need to use initialization list.

Comment: You don't have a default constructor. You don't need it in the code you showed, but your compiler complains that you're trying to use it _somewhere_. To give you a proper answer you would have to give us enough code to reproduce the issue, i.e. a [mcve].

Comment: Did you ever hear of a [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)?

Comment: @MaxLanghof It won't. `Edge::Edge(Node nSource, Node nTarget, int weight) :nSource{nSource}, nTarget{nTarget}, weight{weight} {}` works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was missing the curly braces after the default constructor of Node

```
Node(){};
```

Now it works as intended.
Thanks for the answers, they made me look at the default constructor closer again...

Comment: The code provided had no default constructor at all.

Comment: It was not all of my Code, wanted to keep it short. Sorry for the confusion.